# python monte carlo against dataframe

Tags: python, loops, series

Noobie question here: What is the best way to pass a 1-d array through an equation multiple times to create a series of outcomes?

If I have the following code:

```
montecarlo=randn(1000,1)
tommorows_value=todays_5_day_MA*stdev*montecarlo
```

How do I pass the monte carlo output in this equation to generate 1000 possible outcomes of tomorrow's value?  Would I develop a for loop? tomorrows_value and todays_5_day_MA are pd.Series type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it looks like you are trying to draw 1000 samples from a normal distribution with mean `todays_5_day`, and standard deviation `stddev`.

What you have is almost correct, but you want to add the mean instead of multiply by it.

```
import numpy as np
tomorrows_value = stddev * np.random.randn(1000,1) + todays_5_day
```

See the `Notes` section in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html).

Comment: Let's assume I have the following equation:
x=a+b*c
a and b are single values.  I want to run a monte carlo np.random.randn(1000,1) as the c value to determine all of the possible outcomes for x.
My end goal in mind is to plot a timeseries of data as a line chart and then all my possible "x" values.  The x values are tomorrow's prediction and therefore, will be 1000 unique values for 1 datetime.

Comment: I created the function below:
def montecarlo(a, b):
    randnumgen=np.random.randn(1000,1)
    for i in randnumgen:
        factor=a*i
        for n in factor:
            rt=(b+n)
            return rt
but the result is not what I need since it returns a single value rather than the 1000 possibilities.  In addition, how do I index the 1000 values against the latest datetime only so that I can plot with the timeseries?